# Google Admin SDK: How to use the service account email instead of a privileged user's for retrieving G Suite logs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am using a serverless Python function for retrieving G Suite logs. I have done the following to authenticate against Admin SDK:

1) Created a project
2) Created a service account with the Project->Owner role
3) Create a private key (JSON) file
4) Enabled domain-wide delegation
5) Enabled the Admin SDK
6) Delegate domain-wide authority via 'One or More API Scopes' by authorizing my service account with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly`

Now, when running my authorized application I use 1) the username (privileged user's email address) with access to the created service account and 2) the private key (JSON) file for the service account.

When authorizing my application, I use `ServiceAccountCredentials` from the `oauth2client.service_account` package.

The Question:

When running my application, I can't authorize against G Suite unless I use the username (email address) of a privileged user. When I substitute this email address for the service account's email address, I can't retrieve G Suite logs.

Is it possible to configure the service account to allow authorization via the service account email address? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Service accounts are not part of a G Suite organization. For APIs that require a user identity in G Suite, you need to impersonate (Act As) the user. This is the purpose of Domain-Wide Delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to the question. A service account's email address cannot be used.

The proper steps for retrieving G Suite logs is to either 1) use or 2) create a user with the access rights for reviewing the logs.

If a user must be created, this can be done at the user's console on from [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com/ac/users). After, the appropriate role(s) can be created at [Google IAM](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/roles). Finally, these roles can be applied to the user at the Google Admin console.